# Convert a python list to a Vector

Tags: python, list, matrix, vector

I would like to convert a python list to a Vector (a matrix with a single column). Example: `[1, 2, 3]` should become `[[1], [2], [3]]`.

Comment: `[[x] for x in [1,2,3]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `list comprehension`:

```
>>> [[i] for i in [1,2,3]]
[[1], [2], [3]]
```

or you can also use `map` and `lambda`:

```
>>> map(lambda x: [x], [1, 2, 3])
[[1], [2], [3]]
```